# "Variable out of type PrintStream" error occured

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn Java and have encountered some issues.

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printIn("Hello");
        }
    }
```

Using Notepad++. have the SDK. to compile I used `javac Hello.java`, but it resulted with the following error:

> Symbol: method PrintIn
>
> Location: Variable out of type PrintStream

Comment: use `println()` instead.

Comment: Use an IDE that finds syntax errors.  It will make life so much easier if you are learning.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. you need to write println() not In

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your error is just a typo, happens even to the best of us:

Use a lowercase 'L' instead of an uppercase 'I'; in some IDE's the two look very analogous!

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

Remember: `println()` stands for "print line".

**P.S.** I would recommend a better IDE software such as NetBeans or Eclipse. Both of these catch syntax errors so you don't have to worry.

Comment: @wadie no problem! Typos are just something you'll have to get used to, but using a good IDE always eases the stress. :)

Answer (score 7):

You want `println`, not `printIn`.

Comment: @wadie it does happen, but getting an IDE here helps you learn and get past setbacks like this pretty quick.

Answer (score 6):

It is not

```
System.out.printIn
```

but

```
System.out.println (it's a l)
```

Answer (score 5):

try `System.out.println("Hello");` instead.

Notice the lower case `L` instead of the upper case `I` you have in your example.

`println` is short for *print line*, why they didn't just use `printLine` instead is crazy.
Its not like they avoided vowels in many of the other API methods.

Pick a good IDE with code completion and you won't have these problems going forward.

Comment: I find it helps to remember that "println" stands for "print line".

Answer (score 3):

It's [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)), not `printIn` (lower case "ln" as in short for line)

Answer (score 2):

If that is your actual code the problem is you have a typo in your code.

Method System.out.printin(); does not exist

`System.out.println("Hello");`

You got confused between a lower "l" and a capital "i"

Answer (score 0):

Its not printIn() it is println()