# The difference between the execution of public private in java

Tags: java

```
class pig {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("xixi");
      System.out.println("haha");
   }
   private static void main(String name) 
   {
      System.out.println("你");
   }
```

Comment: Why is my private not executed?

Comment: This site is in English, please only comment in that language.

Comment: It is not executed because there is a syntax error in it. `System.out.printin` should be `System.out.println`  (an `l`, not an `i`)  (see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298980/variable-out-of-type-printstream-error-occured))

Comment: No, after I modified it, my private was not printed out in the console

Comment: Try adding some proper formatting to your question. Very hard to read that code.

Comment: [What is the ``` (3 x backquote) markdown used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189920/what-is-the-3-x-backquote-markdown-used-for)

Comment: I did do the edit again, and change the `i` to an `l`.

Comment: @石生鑫 Why should the private `main()` be executed? There is no line in your code that calls your method.

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replacing-public-with-private-in-main-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

Java expects a single Main method:
`public static void main(String[] args)`

you can declare this method to be private and compile, but at run time there won't be a public main method to be found, so your program won't execute. Your second method is with a String not a String[] <- String array

If you just want to execute what's in your second method, call it in the first main method:

```
class pig {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("xixi");
      System.out.println("haha");
      main();
   }

   private static void main() 
   {
      System.out.println("你");
   }
}
```

You can't have two methods with the same signature in a single class, this goes for private and public alike, so having a main method as public and then also defining the same signature as private is impossible.

In other words, `public int hello()` and `private int hello()` are counted as the same signature. On the other hand, `public int hello(int x)` and `public int hello()` are different signatures and allowed. I hope this clarifies some stuff for you.

The difference between public and private is the following: a private method can only be called within the same class, you can use this to hide methods that are not needed or dangerous to be used from the outside. A public method can be called from the outside.

Let's say you have a class:

```
class Car{
   public hello(){
      System.out.println("Hi");
   }
   private hello2(){
      System.out.println("Hello2");
   }
}
```

And a second class

```
class test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      //we create a car instance here
      Car c = new Car();
      //now we can call the public method here
      c.hello();
      //but if we try to call a private method we get an error
      c.hello2(); //<- this will not execute, is hidden to the outside
   }
}
```

Comment: Please change `printin` to `println` 

Comment: haha just copied that, thanks

Comment: Important to be aware of _won't_ and _wont_ have different meanings, same goes for _can't_ and _cant_. The correct use of apostrophes is important for readability. In a similar vein, _thats_ is invalid, it should be _that's_ or _that is_.

Comment: I'm not native, thank you for pointing that out.